# Image not loading in wordpress add media

Tags: wordpress, media

Has anyone face this problem ? My images are not loading whenever i try to add an image from Add media button/ featured image option in wordpress. It shows an error like this:
An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

Please help if anyone knows the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of factors could be causing this issue.

First - is this a new issue? Have you upgraded/changed anything recently and this began happening?

Second - what are the image sizes? Are they large? Not only in file size but dimensions? Sometimes large images can cause an upload error. Scale them down, both in file size and possibly image size, and see if that helps.

Third - disable your plugins one by one and check the upload again between each plugin. If it's still not uploading when all plug-ins are disabled then activate the default WordPress theme. If it's still not uploading then it may require uninstalling/reinstalling wordpress or even a larger issue that may be out of standard troubleshooting range & would require a more detailed look.